# Huawei Router behind a Mobile Company

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, remote-desktop

So, I have a problem.

I bought a Huawei Router from a Hungarian Telekom provider. This router has a sim card in it. When I type whatsmyip I get one IP address, but the address of the router (WAN IP) is different. From my investigation, I found out that my Router is not going out to the internet directly, but it is behind a Telekom's Router or some kind of device. What that means is that that device is the entry point from the outside.

Now, I have 1 computer attached to this Router and I need to do remote desktop connection on it, but, I can't, since Telekom doesn't allow any Ip Mappings and it cannot throw my router out of their system.

What would be the proposed solution so that I can do a remote desktop connection to this pc?

I know that there are alternatives like TeamViewer and stuff like that, but, in this case, I need a remote desktop connection enabled.

I thought that VPN would solve this, but it looks like I was wrong.

What I thought was that somehow I need to have both of my PCs(one that is on the Huawei router and one from which I will connect through remote desktop connection) on the same network.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are apparently behind
[Carrier-grade NAT (CGN or CGNAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT):

> With CGNAT, end sites, in particular residential networks, are configured with private network addresses that are translated to public IPv4 addresses by middlebox network address translator devices embedded in the network operator's network, permitting the sharing of small pools of public addresses among many end sites.

You will need specialized software to be able to access the computer
from the internet. Some such services are:

- [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/)
- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
- [Nabu Casa](https://www.nabucasa.com/)

You may also ask your ISP for a static IP address (often a paid option),
which will make your router directly reachable from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are behind CGN - which matches your description, a VPN can solve this problem, however you require a specific VPN function which is not ubiquitous - you need the VPN provider to assign you a real IP address.  If you google "Static IP address VPN" you will find the kind of things you are looking for.   They are typically slightly more expensive then a standard VPN.